# Use two buttons (positive/negative) or one and change text?

Tags: android

I'm curious about how other people solve this problem:

When having an application which allows users to subscribe to each other, should you better use two buttons, one with a "Subscribe" text and the other with a "Unsubscribe" text or just use one button in the layout and change the text after clicking the button?

**2 buttons solution**

XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subscribe"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/unsubscribe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unsubscribe"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Java:

```
// update subscribe buttons
if (userProfile.getID() != user.getUserID()) {
    if (userProfile.hasSubscribed()) {
        unsubscribeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        subscribeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

    subscribeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subscribe = 1;
            subscribe();
        }
    });

    unsubscribeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subscribe = -1;
            subscribe();
        }
    });
```

**1 button solution**
XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/subscribe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Java:

```
// update subscribe buttons
if (userProfile.getID() != user.getUserID()) {
    if (userProfile.hasSubscribed()) {
        subscribeView.setText("Unsubscribe");
    }
    else {
        subscribeView.setText("Subscribe");
    }
}

subscribeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (userProfile.hasSubscribed()) {
            subscribe = -1;
        }
        else {
            subscribe = 1;
        }
        subscribe();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use ToggleButton. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Comment: one button seems more clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one-button approach.

Try to keep the UI as clean as possible, and avoid having buttons that are visible, but don't have any effect.